# Book option of the combine document class

Tags: abstract, combine

I included a MWE (a main file and three articles) that uses the `combine` class with `book` option. There are two problems. The formatting process creates the LaTeX Error: Environment abstract undefined, and formatting stops at the first `\begin{abstract}` command in first input file. Press “r” to continue the formatting process. The resulting PDF is almost correct except for the section numbering (0.1, 0.2 … instead of 1, 2 …) in the input article documents. The article documents include the command `\setcounter{section}{0}` in the preamble. The file formats if I replace `book` with `report`, but the section-numbering problem persists. The main document is an accurate example of what I need (A book with parts, several chapters with no input files, and several chapters with input files.) All input files use the article document class. I use MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{The collection}
\author{A. N. Editor}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\ldots
\begin{papers}
    \coltoctitle{First article}
    \coltocauthor{Author of first article}
    \import{inputDoc1}
    \coltoctitle{Second article}
    \coltocauthor{Author of second article}
    \import{inputDoc2}
\end{papers}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\ldots
\begin{papers}
    \coltoctitle{Third article}
    \coltocauthor{Author of third article}
    \import{inputDoc3}    
\end{papers}
\chapter{Chapter 4}
\section{Final introduction}
\end{document} 
%first article
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{First article}
\author{Author of first article}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}
\section{first section}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
%second article
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\begin{document}
\title{Second article}
\author{Author of second article}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{first section}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
%third article
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\begin{document}
\title{Document 1a}
\author{Author of document 1a}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext[3]
\end{abstract}
\section{first section}
\blindtext[1]
\section{second section}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, see `How to construct a collection of articles with LaTeX` available at http://pastcounts.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/how-to-construct-a-collection-of-articles-with-latex/

Comment: You need to define the environment `abstract` and additionally define `acknowledgments`. See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51483/how-to-write-abstract-and-acknowledgement-in-book-format

Comment: Papiro: I read article on pastcounts a few days ago, but I was not able to get the code given there to work with the sample I posted on this forum. I am sure the fault is mine. Thanks for your response.

Comment: cacamailg: I defined an abstract environment but I do not understand why combine does not format input articles as articles. (As I recall, the abstract environment works if I use the report option.) I also do not understand why I need to reset the section counter every time I input an article. The section numbering problem also persists. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @TomPrice BTW, there is another approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/what-is-the-recommended-practice-for-making-multi-article-publications-with-late

Comment: With the code that I paste below I could put it working, and it seemed ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only import articles, and the `article` document class doesn't define the `\chapter` the result is that you will have a value of `0` for the chapters of each imported article. As @Papiro pointed, you can avoid the display of chapter counter with `\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}`. However, with that, you lose the format `\thechapter.\thesection` for the sections in the main document, which in my case would be fine.

Below I present other solution that keeps the format `\thechapter.\thesection` (without the need to add to add `\makeatletter \@ifclassloaded{combine}{\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{savechapter}.\arabic{section}}}{}\makeatother` at each input articles).

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{savechapter}
\AtBeginEnvironment{papers}{\setcounter{savechapter}{\value{chapter}}}
\makeatletter
\let\oldimport\import
\renewcommand*{\import}{\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{savechapter}.\arabic{section}}\oldimport}
\makeatother

% The input articles
\begin{filecontents*}{inputDoc1.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{First article}
\author{Author of first article}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}
\section{first section}
\blindtext[3]
\section{Second section}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{inputDoc2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{Second article}
\author{Author of second article}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{first section}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{inputDoc3.tex}
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{document}
\title{Document 1a}
\author{Author of document 1a}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[3]
\end{abstract}
\section{first section}
\blindtext[1]
\section{second section}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

% Define abstract to be used in book class (or use report)
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51483/how-to-write-abstract-and-acknowledgement-in-book-format
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother


% The main document
\begin{document}
\title{The collection}
\author{A. N. Editor}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\blindtext[1]

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[1]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\ldots
\begin{papers}
    \coltoctitle{First article}
    \coltocauthor{Author of first article}
    \import{inputDoc1}
    \coltoctitle{Second article}
    \coltocauthor{Author of second article}
    \import{inputDoc2}
\end{papers}

\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\ldots
\begin{papers}
    \coltoctitle{Third article}
    \coltocauthor{Author of third article}
    \import{inputDoc3}    
\end{papers}

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\section{Final introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: cacamailg: Thanks for your post. Two problems remain with the section numbering. The first section of an article is not numbered 1., and so on. Sections in the chapters no longer have the chapter number (3.4) for example. The combine package is supposed to typeset abstracts in articles without defining an abstract environment in the main document. However, your fix works well.

Comment: If you like my answer, please upvote it.

Comment: Your code is close to a solution. However, when I add the code \makeatletter \@ifclassloaded{combine}{\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{savechapter}.\arabic{section}}}{}\makeatother
I get the error Missing number, treated as zero... when the formatting process encounters the first section of an article.

Comment: @TomPrice I updated my solution. The code works fine in my computer. I use the latest TeXLive 2012. Try to remove all *.aux *.log *.toc (etc.) files.

Comment: Your updated solution almost worked. The section numbers in the articles did not begin with "1" and they included the chapter number, for example, "2.3". I changed the additional preamble code to 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{savechapter}
\AtBeginEnvironment{papers}{\setcounter{savechapter}{\value{chapter}}}
\makeatletter
\let\oldimport\import
\renewcommand*{\import}{\setcounter{section}{0}\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\oldimport}
\makeatother
which seems to work. Do you see any problem with this?
I appreciate your help. Are you on LinkedIn?

Comment: No problem. If it works, fine! Probably you should mark the question as answered. Soory, but I do not have LinkedIn.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have made considerable progress on the book even though I still have a few things to work out. If you decide to get an account on LinkedIn, feel free to connect with me. You can find me on LinkedIn by searching on my name in the LaTeX group.