# Avoid \thanks text repetition and symbols in article when using multiple titlepages

Tags: titles, article, titling

I am trying to combine three papers written in the article class into one document. Therefore, it is necessary to define three titlepages that contain the authors, the date and the abstract of the respective work. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titling}


\begin{document}

% ----------------------- Article 1 -----------------------
\title{Title 1}
\author{John Doe\thanks{To Horst}}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\newpage
% ----------------------- Article 2 -----------------------
\title{Title 2}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Petra}}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\newpage
% ----------------------- Article 3 -----------------------
\title{Title 3}
\author{John Doe\thanks{bla bla}}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would like to...

- avoid the reappearance of the thank notes from other titles
- avoid any footnotemarks attached to the \thanks

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you combine the PDF files directly? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: That was plan A. I wrote three papers in documentclass article -- all with their own titlepage, own figures, tables and bibliographies. Perfectly compilable. The aim is to combine these three papers, change to continuing page numbers and add a table of contents for the aggregate document. I tried combine [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360822/using-combine-class-raises-undefined-control-sequence-error] -- without success. pdfpages seems to be to limited -- as specially when it comes to building the table of contents. Do you have an idea how to reach my goal in a nice and easy way?

Comment: How should the TOC look like? Just containing the title of the papers or even the sections withing the papers?

Comment: Ideally, it should also have the sections of the papers in addition to the titles of the papers. So it should like this: Paper I: Bla bla, 1. Introduction, 2. Data; Paper II, 1. Introduction, 2. Data etc...

Comment: I will go offline now. Just an advice: In the current form your question and code is a bit messy and unclear. I would provide a very clean example with a minimal amount of code that shows the principle structure. Your preamble, for example, is very large and does not contain much stuff that is actually needed to address your problem.  So I would go for an article document class with multiple title page definitions and some sections and one equation and one figure each. For the figure see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738/. Maybe you get a better marketing then.

Comment: I understand. The idea was to show most of the packages used. Maybe something is interfering with the titlepages.

Comment: I added an example code (sections and TOC are missing) to get the idea. Feel free to delete it if you don't like it.

Comment: **Multiple title pages**: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/

Comment: Maybe search for manual or custom footnotes and footnote symbols or similar. Just don't use thanks at all.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Thanks for asking. An expert at my university helped me out. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `titling` package already provides a command to avoid the
  repetition of the `\thanks` notes: `\emptythanks`. Inserting this
  command after a title will delete the contents from thanks so that
  its content won't appear when using `\thanks` a second time.
- Concerning the footnotemark for the title a simple `\renewcommand\footnotemark{}` will do the job. Then the first footnotemark will be blank. It is important however, to reset the footnote counter to zero before defining `\thanks`: `\setcounter{footnote}{0}`

Here is the solution based on the example in the question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titling}


\renewcommand\footnotemark{}

\begin{document}

% ----------------------- Article 1 -----------------------
\title{Title 1}
\author{John Doe\thanks{To Horst}}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\newpage

% ----------------------- Article 2 -----------------------
\emptythanks
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\title{Title 2}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Petra}}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\newpage
\emptythanks
% ----------------------- Article 3 -----------------------
\title{Title 3}
\author{John Doe\thanks{bla bla}}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Partial solution** -- don't have more time now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{figure}{part}
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\counterwithin*{subsection}{part}
\counterwithin*{equation}{part}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% ----------------------- Article 1 -----------------------
\part{Article 1}
\title{Title 1}
\author{John Doe}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\section{Article 1 Section 1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

% ----------------------- Article 2 -----------------------
\part{Article 2}
\title{Title 2}
\author{John Doe}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\section{Article 2 Section 1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

% ----------------------- Article 3 -----------------------
\part{Article 3}
\title{Title 3}
\author{John Doe}
\date{01.01.2017}
\maketitle

\section{Article 3 Section 1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good starting point. I edited my code to conform with your example. The big question remaining is how to hack the `\thanks` to do what I want.

Comment: @RobertoLiebscher I updated the answer (but not regarding the tahnks). Please upvote if it's helpful. Now the eqation, figure and sections and subsections are numbered within the papers.

Comment: +1 for `counterwithin` I wasn't aware of.